# Spinbox get() method issues

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making an application involving the SpinBox widget. My issue is that whenever I use the get() method to obtain the value after the widget has been clicked. I instead get the value before it was clicked.
Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.geometry('150x150')

        self._box = tk.Spinbox(master, from_ = 0, to = 100)
        self._box.pack(expand = True)
        self._box.bind('<ButtonRelease>', self.func)

    def func(self, event):
        print(int(self._box.get()))

root = tk.Tk()
app = Example(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What's being printed is

```
0 #1st click up | spinbox displays 1
1 #2nd click up | spinbox displays 2
2 #3rd click up | spinbox displays 3
# etc
```

Any help getting around this would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing a bind, set the `command` attribute. This will always be called after the value has changed.

```
self._box = tk.Spinbox(..., command=self.func)
...
def func(self):
    ...
```

Comment: You sir are my hero. You have no idea how long that was messing with me. I was using some entry widgets in conjunction with the spinbox and so  I use bind for all of them to same function. Thank you so much